# why do we have flink-streaming-java and flink-streaming-scala modules in flink source code

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

In Fink source, there are `flink-stream-java` and `flink-stream-scala` modules. Why do we need two modules for flink streaming?

https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-streaming-java

https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-streaming-scala

Answer (score 2):

Both `flink-stream-java` and `flink-stream-scala` provide a similar API to manage Flink Streams ; you only have to use one of them, depending on your language.

Please note that whatever your choice, some dependencies like `flink-runtime` and `flink-clients` depend on a version of `scala` (2.11 or 2.12), because Flink is based on a framework written in `scala`, [Akka](https://akka.io/).

There is an ongoing effort to remove `scala` dependency from a higher level API, `flink-table` ([FLINK-11063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11063)).

Answer (score 0):

**flink-stream-java** is the implement of java api for stream. **flink-stream-scala** is the implement of scala api for stream. So you can find DataStream.java in **flink-stream-java**, and DataStream.scala in **flink-stream-scala**.

Answer (score 0):

These two modules will accomplish the same function, but different developers receive different languages, and personal task scala is more suitable for operator description in languages ​​such as big data, flink spark, etc.